# understanding the pointers in read and write function for device driver

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

The read/write functions each have a parameter `loff_t *f_pos`. I saw in the examples that in the read function it increments the pointer when we read, and in write function it increments this pointer when we write.

Is it the same pointer for both?

```
ssize_t scull_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t count,loff_t *f_pos)
ssize_t scull_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
```

Comment: It's a position at which the current `read` or `write` has to happen. It's up to driver how to handle different (racy) cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reason why use loff\_t \*offp instead of direct filp->f\_pos usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501185/reason-why-use-loff-t-offp-instead-of-direct-filp-f-pos-usage)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But it's a good question. When you implement a driver you set f_pos for your reads and for your writes, and the calling code stores the value you provide. So under the hood there could theoretically be separate read and write file positions.

But the description of [lseek](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/lseek.html) makes it clear that there is a single position for both reads and writes. Otherwise we would need a read_seek() and a write_seek().