# where does loff_t* 's value come from (read,write in device driver)?

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, system-calls

I'm working on linux device driver for my first time.
I'm using the ldd3 book, and some example codes I found online.
So,

I found

```
device_lseek(struct file *file, loff_t offset, int orig)
device_write(struct file *fp, const char *buff, size_t length, loff_t *ppos)
device_read(struct file *fp, char *buff, size_t length, loff_t *ppos)
```

the `lseek` return an `loff_t` (position) and also write the postion into `file->f_pos`

the `read,write` use `ppos` which seems a position.

I want to know where does the value of `ppos` come from ?

Does it have anything to do with the `f_pos` in `file` passed in for `write,read`?

What part of the actions related to position is handled by the kernel system?

What part should a device developer take in charge?

And lastly, where is the document describing these things?

Thanks

Comment: what's the difference between `ppos` and the `f_pos` inside the `file`, why we need both?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reason why use loff\_t \*offp instead of direct filp->f\_pos usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501185/reason-why-use-loff-t-offp-instead-of-direct-filp-f-pos-usage)

Comment: I found the information [here](https://nanxiao.me/en/why-doesnt-linux-device-driver-need-to-update-file-position-in-readwrite-functions/) also.